# How to log query response time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I know you can log all executed queries in a MySQL Server. Is there any way I can log their response time (time MySQl server took to execute the query)? I want to periodically check all the response times for each database in a MySQL server.
For example:

```
SELECT response_time FROM rt_log_table where db_name = 'dbName';
```

P.S. I cannot insert code in the client app. If there is a tool that can help me with that, I can attach to the client.

Thank you very much,

Comment: which response ? from client or only server. note a query - SELECT * from table; can have different response times is the table has 3 rows or 3.000.000 row. So you calculate also the network traffic

Comment: It's the time the MySQL server took to execute a query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the mysql performance scheme to do that (and much more), see [Query Profiling Using Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html) on how to configure it.

The performance scheme is usually enabled by default, but you have to enable query history to log all queries. Once enabled, you can then get query duration by e.g.

```
mysql> SELECT EVENT_ID, TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT/1000000000000,6) as Duration, SQL_TEXT 
    -> FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history_long WHERE SQL_TEXT like '%10001%';
+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| event_id | duration | sql_text                                               |
+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|       31 | 0.028310 | SELECT * FROM employees.employees WHERE emp_no = 10001 |
+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

The log is limited in size, so you might have to periodically query and save that data to another table if you want to preserve it. Logging usually has not much of an impact on performance, but you still might want to enable only what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use microtime() to get the response time, and then maybe INSERT INTO the database to store.
for example

```
<?php
$sql = ....;
$time = microtime(true);
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$diff = microtime(true)-$time;
$milliseconds =  $diff * 1000;
```

You can store `$milliseconds`
I hope this works :-)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the question, but I can't insert code in the client like that. Thank you.